# how can i save a parameter from cakephp2 link

Tags: cakephp

Pls I need to know how I can save into a table a pass parameter from the link. Something like localhost/cake/user/sell/basic. 'basic' is the parameter in that link. How can I retrieve and save it in the action. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption you are saving into your users table and it is a new record.

```
<?php 

class UserController extends AppController{

    public function sell($param = 'basic'){

        $this->User->create();
        $data = ['myParam' => $param];
        $this->User->set($data);
        $this->User->save();
        // do something else eg redirect somewhere
    }

}
```

If you are updating a user your would need to include the user_id as a 2nd parameter and your url would look something like `localhost/cake/user/sell/123/basic`

```
class UserController extends AppController{

    public function sell($id, $param = 'basic'){

        $this->User->id = $id;
        $data = ['myParam' => $param];
        $this->User->set($data);
        $this->User->save();
        // do something else eg redirect somewhere
    }

}
```

Also cakephp convention is to have plural controller names and singular model names. so `UserController` should be `UsersController` which would rename your url to `localhost/cake/users/sell/basic`. Real handy to follow cakephp convention to ensure you get the most of cakes automagic mapping etc

Answer (score 0):

Use cakephp request method

```
  Eg: Use pr($this->request->params); 
  It will show all parameter passed in URL.

  Suppose you have make link this
  echo $this->Html->link(__('add event'), array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'add', '?' => array('id' => 123, 'name' => 'sudhir')));

  Then inside controller action, just call
  pr($this->request->params);  // it will shows all details.
```

You can also use **request** **query** method

```
  Inside controller action, just call
   $id = $this->request->query['id'];
   $name = $this->request->query['name'];
```

Then Use Cakephp **Save** method to store its information in database.